# Unable to connect my android app to my node back with socketio

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I read about this topic, I know lot of people had this but everything I tried failed. With the android emulator or when launch my app on my mobile, it's impossible to connect to my server with socketIo

I downgrade to socketio 1.7 on node to follow tips from another stackoverflow
`"socket.io": "^1.7.2",`
Android side, I have this version

```
implementation ('io.socket:socket.io-client:2.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
```

Here is some codes I have:

Node server:

```
const io = new Server(server)

const app = express()


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port " + PORT) 
})

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("Connection established")

    socket.on('room', function(room) {
        console.log(room);
    })

    socket.on('disconnect', function(connectionObject) {
        io.emit()
    })
})
```

I have those in the AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
            ...
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

By the way, I have a warning "Unknown attribute android:usesCleartextTraffic". I saw that it was implemented for sdk23 so I put minSDKVersion to 23 in my build.gradle

Then I have my Object with my socket and function like this:

```
lateinit var msocket: Socket

    @Synchronized
    fun setSocket() {
        try {
            msocket = IO.socket("http://127.0.0.1:3000")
            // I tried 10.0.2.2, my ipv4 192.168.1.x
            println(msocket.id())
        } catch (e: URISyntaxException) {
            println(e.localizedMessage)
        }
    }

    @Synchronized
    fun getSocket() : Socket{
        return msocket
    }
```

The log with my socket.id is null.
Those functions are called from my activity on an onClick event:

```
    private fun connectToWebSocket() {
        SocketHandler.setSocket()
        val msocket = SocketHandler.getSocket()
        msocket.connect()
        Log.i("info", msocket.isActive.toString())
        msocket.emit("room", "RoomName")
    }
```

The log on this function display false, the socket is not active

And none of my console.log on my server are displayed too